# pandas dataframe, How do I select the N surrounding points by index

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with 200 rows and a point X. I need to select the N nearest points by index. N can be an even or an odd number.

Lets say my N in this case is 20. How can I get the closest 20 points to X by index. This would have to work if X is say at index 5, so I can't just take an the 10 points in either direction. Is there something in pandas where you say

```
df.getClosest(index=5, N=20)
```

And it will return the subset of the dataframe with the 20 points closest the point at index 5?

Comment: Something like this? `n = 20`  with `df.iloc[(5-n):(5+n)]`

Comment: There is a couple problems with that. First of all it would include the index I started with. Also, if n is larger than 5, you end up doing df.iloc[-val:+val]. If iloc takes a negative value it ends up taking indexes from the end of frame. So if n=20, then it would take index 185 to 200 along with 0 to 5. Also it would take like n*2 points not n

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
# Set Index to Search
index_to_search = 5

# Create an Index Column
df['Index'] = df.index

df_new = df.iloc[(df['Index']-index_to_search).abs().argsort()[:20]]

print(df_new['Index'].tolist())
```

I assumed you didn't have an "Index" column on your data frame. If you already do, then you shouldn't need the `df['Index'] = df.index` line.

I think if you have two ID's that are closest (one below and one above for example) it favours the smaller one. But this potential issue will only apply if you need an even number of indexes.